# Binding background with string path

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to bind string (which is a path to png) in ViewModel to grid background. This string can be null. It works good but in output cmd is

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '' from type '' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter

How I can bind a string path to the background to avoid this error?
My current binding:
FieldControl.CS:

```
        public string BackgroundPath
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(BackgroundPathProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BackgroundPathProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundPathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundPath", typeof(string), typeof(FieldControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

FieldControl.XAML:

```
        <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush
            ImageSource="{
                    Binding Path=BackgroundPath,  
                    Mode=OneWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                    RelativeSource={
                                    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}
                                   }
                 }" />

    </Grid.Background>
```

And in MainWindow.XAML:

```
        <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding FieldsVM}">

        ...

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:FieldControl
                    BackgroundPath="{Binding Path=BackgroundPath }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Why is the type identifier in the Compiler Error Empty?

Comment: I think it is because the string is null. This value is changing when the program is running. It works good and when I send path as a background it is changing but when it is null I can see this error in logs but the program isn't crushing

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ImageSource Binding is pointless. The Binding is OneWay by default, and UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Thanks for a note, I am new in WPF and this whole binding stuff so I know there can be many stupid lines of code

Comment: TargetNullValue is some value that ll be placed when the current binding value is null? If I am correct what value I can set? When there is null I don't want to have background

Comment: In order to avoid the error message, set the Binding's TargetNullValue (maybe to an empty DrawingImage). Or write an appropriate Binding Converter that deals with a null value. Or just ignore the error message. It doesn't hurt.

Comment: ~"It doesn't hurt." Does it make the app slower? I am setting this null value over 100 times when the app starts, has it any influence to performance?

Comment: No, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Okay, I trust You :D Thanks

Comment: The notification of a value change does incur some cost. At worst, even pointless redraws/processing However, the code responsible for the work usually checks if there was a *actuall* change. In a setter, if the `currentValue == inputValue`, you do not raise ChangeNotification, Validation or do anything else that would cost resources. Whoever holds a stake in the value, already retreived the current value after registering change notification event. I am hoping thise code does as well.

Comment: Like the compiler said, consider create a IValueConverter, to convert from string to [ImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imagesource?view=netcore-3.1), or change the BackgroundPathProperty type to ImageSource

Comment: Yes, I noticed this. When I am setting value when a program is running from null to null it doesn't show error

Comment: @Marlonchosky, I thought about it but I don't know how exactly Converter should look

Comment: @iknow I write an answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove the error from the compiler, is to create an IValueConverter and using in the ImageBrush element, as the compiler suggest.

The IValueConverter could be writing like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(ImageSource))]
public class StringToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (value == null) return null;

        var path = value.ToString();
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

and in the FieldControl's xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:StringToImageSourceConverter x:Key="StringToImageSourceConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Height="100">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=BackgroundPath, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=Uc1, 
                    Converter={StaticResource StringToImageSourceConverter}}" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

After this, you shouldn't see the error from the compiler.

I test the code in [this](https://github.com/marlonedu/WpfTests/tree/master/WpfApp21) project.

Comment: Yes it works (I have to add "pack://application:,,," at the beginning of string), I don't see any errors. Thanks

Comment: @iknow Question: Is it necessary, for your project, to define the type of BackgroundPath as a string? could it change to another type?

Comment: No, it's not necessary but I am having 121*4 BackroundPaths so I decided to not keep it as an image but as a string. It uses less memory. What other type can be good to keep so many images paths?

Comment: You can change the type to ImageSource instead of string. I don't think (but not sure) that your application will suffers if your change the type, since the WPF framework use a technique named Virtualization for lists (read [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel?view=netcore-3.1]). Nevertheless, you can test the change of the type and then do a profiling of your app using the Diagnostic Tools Window in Visual Studio.